# Smooth mouse scrolling - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I've been looking for a while and so far I can only find either bad examples or mouse scrolls with anchors, I'm trying to get a effect like [this](http://www.borislavninic.com/) for my mouse scroll.

Would anyone know where I could download a plugin for jquery like this or have any tips for making it myself?

Thanks

### Update

Chrome officially supports smooth scrolling, using this library is no longer recommended as it simply conflicts with the built in scrolling capabilities.

Comment: You're not explaining what *exactly* you want. Every browser gives you 'smooth scrolling', as long as you don't saturate the browser with javascript, too many images, videos ... Do you mean you want the parallax effects in that page?

Comment: @OscarPaz I simply need the scrolling efect that isn't a hard scroll like for example stack overflow, simply so it scrolls down smoothly as you scroll your mousewheel down

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean jquery parallax. It's a plugin to manage layers.

http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented jQuery.ScrollTo to good effect before now: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

You can hook this up to the mousewheel event as well as clickable elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [this one](https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll),
under the :

```
var defaultOptions = {
```

there are some vars you have to modify before embedding into your page to suit your style.

Well, another style using jQuery, take a look into the source [js/plugins-scroll.js](http://premiumlayers.com/demos/tempcore/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll

As far as I know it was made specifically for Google Chrome. I haven't tried it on any other browser.

If you're also looking for smooth drag effects (mobile and mouse enabled) try:

http://iscrolljs.com/

Comment: The links you've included may answer the question, but it would be better to summarize their content as well. That will ensure that your answer is still useful if the linked content changes or becomes unavailable.